# Sending Bash Aliases to detached screen sessions

Tags: bash, shell, alias, gnu-screen

I'm on a Linux machine using `screen`, and I'm attempting to write a (fairly portable) function which runs a bash function in a new, detached screen session which automatically closes upon completion.  I've had some success, but I noticed the following behavior:

If I include the definition of `mail_submit()` in my `~/.bashrc` file, I can run

```
    mail_submit foo
```

in the terminal, and also I can access the alias in a new screen session:

```
    screen -S test
    mail_submit foo
```

*However*, the following command *does not work*:

```
    screen -d -m -S test sh -c 'mail_submit foo'
```

presumably because `sh -c` starts a fresh shell that has no knowledge of my `~/.bashrc` profile.  So, I can use the following fix:

```
    screen -d -m -S test sh -c 'source ~/.bashrc; mail_submit foo'
```

which *does* work.

But if I want to wrap this functionality up into a bash alias (which is my ultimate goal here), this will cause a weird self-referential situation.

**Question:** What is an easy way to either have sh -c know the location of my `~/.bashrc` profile, or use a variant of sourcing the file and creating an alias?

**EDIT:** I could save the shell script in my home directory, and create an alias which runs

```
    screen -d -m -S test bash -c '~/mail_submit.sh $1'
```

but I'd still be curious to hear other possible fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default `~/.bashrc` contains this (`[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return`) little piece of code on top of it (or somewhere else in the upper part). This line will prevent the `~/.bashrc` from beeing sourced if the bash shell doesn't run in interactive mode.

You could:

1. Remove this line
2. Create a new file which will only contain the alias you need and source that
3. Create a little bash script instead of an alias and run that

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `screen -d -m -S test bash -c 'mail_submit foo'`?
It looks like you're trying to run the command with the shell (sh), and not the bourne again shell (bash), which is the shell interpreter which actually reads the `~/.bashrc` profile.

Edit: The .bashrc file is not being sourced by default because screen does not create the bash process as a login shell, which is when the .bashrc file is read. Creating a .screenrc file with the line `defshell -bash` will create the bash process as a login shell instead, which will then call the .bashrc file.

Comment: Good catch; unfortunately the problem persists, and is likewise fixed when I explicitly source `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Try setting up a ~/.screenrc file with `defshell -bash` in it, which makes bash run as a login shell, which will call the ~./.bashrc file, since by default, screen will not run bash as a login shell (which is when the .bashrc file is read). See this post for more information: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=82519